# Forward traffic from first to second server

Tags: linux, dns, forwarding, traffic

I have 2 Servers, 1 normal Server without ddos protection and 1 ddos protected v-Server,

i try to forward traffic through the v server to the main server.
So if someone access to my v-server like tcp 80 or udp 9987 then it will redirect it to my server and the same vice versa...

so my plan is to make the v-server like an router ... 
vserver -> linux debian 7
main server -> windows 2012 r2

p.s. if possible ways without ssh

has anyone ideas ? thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be setting up DNAT with `iptables` on v-Server.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <main-server>
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 9987 -j DNAT --to-destination <main-server>

# This is needed to correctly return response packets to hosts in the same subnet.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j SNAT --to-source <v-Server>
```

You should specify `<main-server>` or `<v-Server>` as IP addresses in the example above.

Alternatively it could be setting up LVS/DR with `ipvsadm` which seems a bit bloating.

For tcp/80 traffic you could also set up a proxy server using `nginx` or something like it.

Comment: The two `iptables` rules won't be enough if he wants to access the two ports of v-Server from the same subnet. SNAT is also required.

Comment: i did not understand and i just will forward the hole traffic so all ports execpt ssh

Comment: @petry Oh yeah I arbitrarily assumed v-Server is a default router for main-server.  I updated my post.  Thanks!

Comment: oh god what did i actually forgot ? its telling me everytime:
" iptables v1.4.18: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?) "

Comment: @ProJaCore Could you be more specific on your servers (distribution, hardware, virtualization, etc.) ?

Comment: i just installed ubuntu now and just try to configure...
ubuntu-13.10-x86_64,1 x 3,9 GHz Xeon E5,1 GB Ram,10 GB HDD

Comment: @ProJaCore I bet you're running your servers on VPS service like AWS EC2 which could cause the problem.  Anyway you'd better post another question for it.  Describe your situation in detail as much as you can there.